# Segmentation fault when using array

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct StockDetail {
    char* name;
    int code;
    int price;

} Stock;

int main(void)
{
    Stock a[200]; int i; int b;
    for(i=0; i<20 ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Stock %i\n",i+1);
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s",a[i].name);
        printf("Code:");
        scanf("%i",&a[i].code);
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%i",&a[i].price);

    }

    printf("Maximum price of the stock:");
    scanf("%i", &b);

    for(i=0; i<20 ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].price<=b)
        {
            printf("%s\n",a[i].name);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to implement a program that reads 20 stock details such as name, code and price and then ask the user to input a maximum price and print out the stock that cost less than the price. The code looks fine but when I tried to run it gave "segmentation fault" error line.

Comment: Next time try to produce a [mcve]! there are more lines that are *not* executed than there are lines that actually are.

Answer (score 7):

You do not allocate any space for your `Stock.name`.  Use a `char[100]` or allocate some space.

something like:

```
for(i=0; i<20 ; i++ )
{
    char tempname[100];
    printf("Stock %i\n",i+1);
    printf("Name:");
    scanf("%s",tempname);
    a[i].name=strdup(tempname);
```

Don't forget to free it!

Otherwise declare

```
typedef struct StockDetail {
char name[100];
int code;
int price;

} Stock;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
scanf("%s",a[i].name);
```

Here you are taking input in name which is just `char*` it does not have memory alloted to it, you can declare it as char array with sufficient size or allocate memory with malloc before taking input in it